# Index for date part of field?

Tags: mysql, index, mysql-5.6

I have a datetime field, but I often query over the date part, like this

```
select * from table where date(datetime_field)=curdate()
```

This query can't use  index on datetime_field!
What would be the best solution with the minimum amount of changes in code or db?

PS. upgrading mysql could be an option if there is a solution I'm not aware of yet, but a more short term solution for 5.6 would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't the index.  The problem is that your query as written does not allow an index to be used.

Modify your query so that the date range is resolved to a pair of constants and the problem is solved:

```
WHERE datetime_field >= CURDATE()
  AND datetime_field < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

This will use the index on the column.

As a rule, never use a column as an argument to a function in `WHERE` because this forces a table scan.

Answer (score 2):

There is very much a solution for you if you upgrade.

You could have:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
  field_1 TYPE_1 NOT NULL, -- &c...
  field_2 TYPE_2 NOT NULL, --..
  ..
  datetime_field DATETIME,
  ..
  field_n TYPE_N, --  ...

  my_date_field DATE GENERATED ALWAYS AS (DATE(datetime_field)) VIRTUAL,
  INDEX my_date_field_ix (my_date_field)
);
```

`GENERATED` (aka `COMPUTED` or `CALCULATED`) fields are available for [MySQL 5.7.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) on! If you can't/don't want to upgrade, then the common solution is to implement this using triggers. The advantage with this solution  is that you don't have to have any extra storage (`VIRTUAL`), but with HDDs so cheap nowadays, that's not really an issue anymore!

This handy functionality is provided free, *gratis* and for nothing by the server. Your datum is still stored in one and only one place a SPOT (Single Point Of Truth - or [SSOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth)), so no data duplication/inconsistency issues **and** you get to use an `INDEX` for "free". Give it a try - I think they're great!

Noticed @Michael-sqlbot's reply - way more elegant for this case, but sometimes, it can be difficult to make your query arguments [sargable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable)!